# Is every eigenvector of $T$ is also eigenvector of $g(T)?$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, linear-transformations

Let's say I have a linear transformation $T: V\longrightarrow V$ and a polynomial $g(x)$.
I'm trying to prove that every eigenvector $v$ of T is also an eigenvector of $g(T)$.
any hint of how to prove this statement?

Comment: Expand $g(T)v$ to get $ g(\lambda) v$.

Comment: If $v\in V$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, I think it's not too difficult to guess what should be the eigenvalue of $v$ as an eigenvector of $g(T)$.

Comment: How is that? I saw in some places that it is $g(\lambda)$ but I still can't figure a way to prove it

Comment: What is the definition of $g(T)$? What happens when you apply that definition to the expression $g(T)(v)$?

Comment: Ok, so I now proved that $g(T)v=g(\lambda)v$ but still can't see if this really prove the statement or that something is missing here!

Comment: What I mean, does $g(T)v=g(\lambda)v$ means that v is eigenvector of $g(T)$ with eigenvalue of $g(\lambda)$?

Comment: You'd better sit down and master the basic definitions!

Comment: I know the basic definition but its the first question I solve where polynomials are included, so if don't have answer don't just throw words on me.

Comment: @BlackHat What, by definition, does it mean for a transformation $A$ to have eigenvector $x$ with associated eigenvlaue $k$? Now take that definition, plug in $A = g(T), x = v,$ and $k = g(\lambda)$.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, as everyone has already said in the comments.... This is a very easy problem that is simply the application of the definition of an eigenvector. I'm also aware that this forum generally frowns upon spoon feeding answers to such questions. However, I've always hated it when I have genuine questions, don't know where to start and the only answer I can find is to "think harder". I don't generally find such "hints" to be helpful although I do agree with Prof. Shifrin in this particular case.

Let $$g(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$$

Therefore, we have;

$$g(T)=a_nT^n+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+...+a_1T+a_0$$

It should be fairly obvious from the definition of an eigenvector that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ then;

$$T^nv=\lambda^nv$$

Now apply this to our polynomial $g(T)$ and we get that;

$$g(T)v=(a_n\lambda^n+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+...+a_1\lambda+a_0)v$$

So $v$ is, indeed, an eigenvector of $g(T)$ if it is an eigenvector of $T$.

Comment: Yes, sometimes there is no point in demanding that novices "think harder"... because one's mind can inexplicably get stuck on issues that turn out to be mere phantoms... but do interrupt one's thinking. And, by this year I have the principle that, in teaching, if I want to claim that something is "obvious", then I should be able to persuade people in just a line or two... As opposed to the traditional "it's so obvious I can't explain it"...

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Prove that if $Tv = \lambda v$, then $T^n v = \lambda^n v$. From this it follows that every polynomial in $T$ has the same eigenvectors as $T$.